# Django RF + React JS, How to check in frontend whether any user is being logged in?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I use Django Rest Framework in backend and React in frontend for my Blog project.

In Django templates if we use `{{user}}` method, we will know if anybody being logged in.

But I am unable to use the above method in React JS environment.

Should I send a test create (POST) request to server to check that ?

Any better idea ?

Comment: You are asking how to authenticated a user. Once that user is authenticated you should simply store that in the state of your React app. As far as the mode of authentication you should probably use sessions or JWTs. Don't send a "test" request that could create unwanted data in your database.

Comment: Thanks, I am using session auth, after user close browser without logout, the session id still active. In this situation what shall do ?

Comment: Invalidating or expireing a session is beyond the scope of this question. Please either update your question or post a new one.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is, after user  logged in using session auth. I have to change some component properties such as logout , profile etc so I needed a method . Currently I send a request to server and if user loggedin I use the response in Global state.